# Как изменится нагрузка на процессор?

Tags: процессор

Модуль камеры ov7670 передает данные на дисплей, используя DMA (Direct Memory Access). Ответьте на вопрос, как изменится нагрузка на центральный процессор, связанная с модулем камеры, если увеличить частоту процессора в 2 раза?

Comment: Никак не изменится.

Comment: Модуль камеры не может ничего передавать на дисплей и нагрузка зависит, от того что делает процессор (или GPU) между камерой и видео. Замечу ещё, что при большом fps зачастую бОльшую роль чем скорость процессора играет скорость памяти